# Using Queue in Multi-Threading returns address of function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a multi-threading program which finds out prime numbers over multiple threads and aggregates their result.

I am using a queue to actually store the returned values. but when I print the values of queue only the address of the function is printed

```
n = int(input("Enter the value:"))

def task1():
    global n 
    print("Task 1 assigned to thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name)) 
    print("ID of process running task 1: {}".format(os.getpid()))
    a=[] 
    for i in range(2,n//2):
        c=0
        for j in range(2,i+1):
            if(i%j==0):
                c+=1
        if(c<=1):
            a.append(i)
    return a
    
    

def task2():
    global n
    print("Task 2 assigned to thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name)) 
    print("ID of process running task 2: {}".format(os.getpid())) 
    a=[] 
    for i in range(n//2+1,n):
        c=0
        for j in range(2,i+1):
            if(i%j==0):
                c+=1
        if(c<=1):
            a.append(i)
    return a
        
import queue
que=queue.Queue()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda q: q.put(task1), args=(que,), name='t1') 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda q: q.put(task2), args=(que,), name='t2') 

  # starting threads Spawn
t1.start() 
t2.start() 

  # wait until all threads finish Sync
t1.join() 
t2.join()

while not que.empty():
    result=que.get()
    print(result)
```

after running the code, this is the value I am getting

```
<function task1 at 0x00000204A9A11438>
<function task2 at 0x00000204A9A11288>
```

I need to print the array of prime numbers instead of the address.

Comment: "I am using a queue to actually store the returned values." - uh, no? No part of this code stores the returned values in the queue. No part of this code even runs `task1` or `task2`. You just launched two threads that add `task1` and `task2` themselves to the queue, then retrieved the functions from the queue.

Comment: it does .. If I just print something instead of the original task the function is working , it's just when returning the value its giving me this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target` is the function to run in the thread.  What you've made the thread do (and *only* do) is add a function reference to the queue.  Your task are not run.

Fixes:

1. Set the task functions to each target.
2. Since threads run in the same process, the queue can be accessed without passing it as a parameter.  Same with the lock below.
3. Write the results to the queue.
4. `global n` isn't needed.  It's only needed if you want to reassign `n`.
5. Create a lock to manage printing if you will print in threads.  It can get mixed up otherwise.
6. Add appropriate imports (why do questioners *always* leave off the imports???)

You'll also find that this likely runs slower than simply computing primes in one non-parallel task.  Python processes are restricted by the global interpreter lock (GIL) to run Python code in only one thread at a time, so the threads are serialized if they run CPU-bound work, which this is.

Threads are ideal for parallelizing I/O bound work.  Use processes via the `multiprocessing` module to run CPU-bound tasks, but note that the overhead of creating processes and the inter-process communication to send parameters and results back to the main process can overwhelm simple CPU-bound operations like this, unless they run for a significant period of time.

```py
import threading
import os
import queue

n = int(input("Enter the value:"))

lock = threading.Lock()
que = queue.Queue()

def task1():
    with lock:
        print("Task 1 assigned to thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name)) 
        print("ID of process running task 1: {}".format(os.getpid()))
    a=[] 
    for i in range(2,n//2):
        c=0
        for j in range(2,i+1):
            if(i%j==0):
                c+=1
        if(c<=1):
            a.append(i)
    que.put(a)
    
def task2():
    with lock:
        print("Task 2 assigned to thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name)) 
        print("ID of process running task 2: {}".format(os.getpid())) 
    a=[] 
    for i in range(n//2+1,n):
        c=0
        for j in range(2,i+1):
            if(i%j==0):
                c+=1
        if(c<=1):
            a.append(i)
    que.put(a)
        
t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t1') 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=task2, name='t2') 

  # starting threads Spawn
t1.start() 
t2.start() 

  # wait until all threads finish Sync
t1.join() 
t2.join()

while not que.empty():
    result=que.get()
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
Enter the value: 100
Task 1 assigned to thread: t1
ID of process running task 1: 3864
Task 2 assigned to thread: t2
ID of process running task 2: 3864
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
[53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `task1` and `taks2` (which are both functions) in the queue:

```
.put(task1)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda q: q.put(task1), args=(que,), name='t1')
```

so when you read back its contents - you get functions as well.

Also, even though you seem to intent to pass queue `que` as an argument, the functions `task1` and `taks2` are parameterless. I also don't understand the usage of lambda in constructors of threads but that is another matter.

Since it seems like a homework I am only narrowly answering your question and not provide full working example.

Comment: I searched on stackoverflow on how to return the values and using the lambda function was one of the ways I got.